# Emulating a click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been looking for a simple solution to this particular problem, and havent' been able to do much with it.

I'm making a site right now, and have a rotator. Below it is a nested accordion I've been playing with. Essentially, I want a column to expand when an image in the rotator is clicked.

I've pushed the example I'm talking about here:
http://djsbydesign.com/new/index2.html

Edit: I want each of the four images to expand a different column in the accordion. This can also be achieved by clicking on an element within a column of the accordion. I don't know how to have the slides in the rotator trigger a click that does this.

Comment: please put some code, and explain a little bit more your issue

Comment: Explained the issue a bit more, I'll add some code as well.

Comment: Alright, I didn't understand that .click() not only bound an element to an event, but also could trigger that event. Thanks to everyone, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('element-id').click();
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you obviously don't have a problem using jQuery, what is stopping you from just doing

```
$(theElement).click();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery. 
`$('#element').click();`

Answer (score 3):

JQuery .trigger()

```
$(elem).trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just find the element using valid selector and call the `click` method on it.

```
$('validSelector').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(".info-col:nth-child(1) dl dt:nth-child(1)").click()
```

where the first nth-child is the column number and the second is the row number.

**Edit:** Actually, the code is not consistent enough to use the above.  That assumes a div with class name of info-col, a nested dl, and then nested dt.  They're not all the same structure.  If they were, that would work.